# How to move an object with a selected speed to the mouse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I move an object to the mouse with a specific speed?
I mean like it moves towards the mouse with (20px/s) and its not matter how far the mouse is.
My code is:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 mousePosition;
    public float moveSpeed = 0.02f;
    
    void Update()
    {
        mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        mousePosition.z += Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Because using this (This is the only code I found online) if the mouse is far away the object move faster.

-Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That is what `lerp` does by definition. You can use `MoveTowards` instead.

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: @Meskyy404 accept the answer if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 farePos=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,10f));
    transform.position=new Vector3(farePos.x,transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
}
```

**
This code moves the object left and right with the mouse.
You can bind the code to the object and use it.
He usually does my job.**